# Where is getchar() besides cstdio?

Tags: c++, libraries

I'm taking my first c++ class (and I'm in week 6.)

I used getchar(), which according to every reference I can find, is located in cstdio (or stdio or stdio.h.)  Just to see what would happen I commented out

```
#include <cstdio>
```

Much to my surprise, my program still ran without errors.  Other libraries I included are: algorithm, cstdlib, iostream, and string.  I take it that getchar() is a part of one of these other libraries, but searching the internet, I don't see any reference that mentions any non-cstdio-like library.

Is cstdio and cstdlib the same thing?

Is there a definitive reference for what libraries hold each method/command?

Thank you for tolerating my noob questions.  ~d

Comment: AFAIK `getchar` is only guaranteed to be in `stdio.h` and `std::getchar` is only guaranteed to be in `cstdio`. You cannot rely on getting it from other headers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that one of your other header files is also including `<cstdio>` or it's equivalent (I would guess `<iostream>`).

Including `<cstdio>` is the right thing to do. If you don't then you might find that your code stops compiling when it's used with a different compiler.

BTW header files are not libraries, and the definitive references for what is found in which header file are the C++ and C standards documents.

Also BTW this kind of experimentation is exactly the sort of thing you should be doing as a new C++ programmer.

Comment: Actually, I don't think `cstdio` is *guaranteed` to have `getchar` outside of the `std` namespace (although it is allowed to).